# Problem fetching data from table using foreach loop

Tags: php, sql

I am having problem in fetching data from database table, after loading data into array and loop using foreach it return blank instead of the values. I have tried using this way `$row['']` it works fine but i want to use this operand `->` but its fetching bank data.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM pages_words";

$select_posts = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$rows[] = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_posts))
$rows[] = $row;

foreach ($rows as $key => $row) {
    $idpw = $row['idpw'];
    $pages = $row['pages'];
    $words = $row['words'];
    $amount_added = $row['amount_added'];
    $page_type = $row['page_type'];
    if ($page_type == 'double') {
        if ($row->idpw == $post['no_of_pages']) {
            echo '<option selected="selected" id="' . $row->idpw . 'nop" value="' . $row->idpw . '" title="' . $row->amount_added . '"> ' . $row->pages . ' Page(s) / ' . $row->words . ' Words</option>';
        } else {
            echo '<option id="' . $row->idpw . 'nop" value="' . $row->idpw . '" title="' . 
            $row->amount_added . '"> ' . $row->pages . ' Page(s) / ' . $row->words . ' Words</option>';
        }

    }

}

?>
```

[blank data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWFB4.png)
kindly help solve the problem

Comment: There is no reason to fetch all the rows and then to use another loop to go through them. you can do all the job perfectly just in the first `while()` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You used `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`, which fetches rows as associative arrays. In other places in the foreach loop, you're accessing the row correctly using array syntax, such as `$idpw = $row['idpw'];`. You can't access array values using object syntax. Instead of using `$row->idpw` when outputting the option, you could either use `$row['idpw']` or just use the `$idpw` variable you created earlier.

If you want the arrow operator to work, you'll need to use `mysqli_fetch_object()` instead, but if you do that you'll need to change the places where you're using array syntax to use object syntax as well.